# Java equals string and object from ObservableList

Tags: javafx, tableview, equals

I have a big problem. My code:

```
TablePosition pos = (TablePosition)
     tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0);
Object item = tableView.getItems().get(pos.getRow());
Object e = ((List<ObservableList>) item).get(0);
String new_status = "textExample";
```

and how can I use equals ? `new_status.equals(e)` ? I don't have any idea on how to convert this.

p.s. in console e = "textExample".

I need this to update a sql row.

Comment: Im not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I want to compare: object "e" and string "new_status"

Comment: Can you use fewer raw types? E.g. your `tableView` should be declared as `TableView<Something> tableView ;` Then the type of `item` would be whatever that `Something` was (presumably `List<ObservableList<SomethingElse>>`). If you get rid of the raw types this should become much easier.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get selected items, you can just use [`getSelectedItems()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MultipleSelectionModel.html#getSelectedItems--) (or [`getSelectedItem()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#getSelectedItem--) if you only want the latest selection). You don't need to work with selected cells, table positions and rows.

Assuming a `TableView<ObservableList<String>>` (which you may or may not have).  Code to retrieve the value of the first element of the selected row (probably the value represented in the first column), would be as follows:

```
    final String NEW_STATUS = "textExample";

    final TableView<ObservableList<String>> tableView = new TableView<>();
    final ObservableList<String> selectedItem = 
            tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    if (selectedItem != null 
            && !selectedItem.isEmpty() 
            && NEW_STATUS.equals(selectedItem.get(0))) {
        // do work here.
    }
```

As your type definitions may be different you may need to adapt the code above to fit your situation as required.  If you still can't work it out, you will need to edit the question to provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get further assistance.